# intellij: root and root-build removed, sbt dependencies are broken

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I open up the intellij and immediately there was a pop up window with the following message:

Modules bellow are not imported from SBT anymore. Check those to be removed from the idea project.

[image]

And it was already selected. I clicked ok but now by sbt file is all read respect to dependencies.

[image]

I actually did go to File >> Invalidate Caches / Restart but still the same error.

Is there way to go back and recover or if not how can I resolve sbt dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing this issue, just rename the `root` in the line `lazy val root = ..` to the one in your matching your run configuration `Play2 Module`

To do this go `Run` -> `Edit Configuration`, then look for `Play2 Module`.

From the dropdown match that name with the one in your `build.sbt`